# Hover effect not working proper in IE browser

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, css

I am using css to give hover effect(Change background position) with sprite images, its work fine in fire fox but does work fine in IE browser, anything that I need to add in below code?

```
.social ul li { width:32px; height:32px; float:left; margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;
padding:20px 0px;}
.social ul li:last-child { margin:0px}
.social ul li.twitter a{ background:url(../images/grey_bg_sprite.png) no-repeat 0px
-192px; width:32px; height:32px;}
.social ul li.twitter a:hover {background:url(../images/grey_bg_sprite.png) no-repeat 0px
-226px; width:32px; height:32px; }
```

Comment: Show a Fiddle. Use JSFIDDLE.NET

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of IE, a:hover will not work if your `<a>` does not have an href with a non-empty string in it.  So, if your a looks like this:  `<a class="foo">Bar</a>` then it needs to have an href like this:  `<a href="#" class="foo">Bar</a>`  Older versions of IE will not consider it a valid anchor tag without a filled href attribute and so will ignore the :hover psuedoclass.